# Can't write JSON string in Groovy/Java

Tags: java, json, groovy

So I am trying to write the following JSON as a Java string but getting an error I don't understand:

```
    String simpleAPI_MessageInJSON = "{                                          " +
                                 "       \"action\": \"add\",                    " +
                                 "       \"destinations\": {                     " +
                                 "           \"cache\": 1,                       " +
                                 "           \"batches\": 1                      " +
                                 "        },                                     " +
                                 "       \"payload\": {                          " +
                                 "           \"object_type\": \"profile\",       " +
                                 "           \"object_id\": 366334,              " +
                                 "        }                                      " +
                                 "    }                                          ";
```

ERROR:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

Comment: If this is groovy, use triple quoted string so you do not need to write the escape characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma:

```
"           \"object_id\": 366334,              " +
```

Should be:

```
"           \"object_id\": 366334              " +
//                              /\ Extra comma was there.
```

The error message says:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

This isn't very clear, but we can make out that it's a syntax error of some kind, and it has a line number. By looking around the line number, you can find the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally easier to use multi-line strings if you are using groovy for improved readability:

```
String simpleAPI_MessageInJSON = '''{                                          
                                   |    "action": "add",
                                   |    "destinations": {
                                   |        "cache": 1,
                                   |        "batches": 1
                                   |    },
                                   |    "payload": {
                                   |        "object_type": "profile",
                                   |        "object_id": 366334
                                   |    }
                                   |}'''.stripMargin()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what [stripMargin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#stripMargin()) does :-)

Comment: oops, I was so mesmerized by your beautifully aligned pipes, that I totally missed that.

Comment: That's groovy for you... 80% useful with 20% hypnotism ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Annubian Noob

Strange, works with groovy:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String simpleAPI_MessageInJSON = "{                                          " +
                                 "       \"action\": \"add\",                    " +
                                 "       \"destinations\": {                     " +
                                 "           \"cache\": 1,                       " +
                                 "           \"batches\": 1                      " +
                                 "        },                                     " +
                                 "       \"payload\": {                          " +
                                 "           \"object_type\": \"profile\",       " +
                                 "           \"object_id\": 366334,              " +
                                 "        }                                      " +
                                 "    }  "
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(simpleAPI_MessageInJSON)
assert parsed.action == "add"
```